# Continuously update text with scraped value from a website

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, phantomjs

I got my program to scrape a value from a web page after post login with PhantomJs but the value(balance) updates every other minute.

What do I need it to do to continuously update label in my Windows Form (like every five minutes) as the web page updates the value. So would I need a loop for that?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
var points = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(
  "#site-header > div > div > div.col-xs-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > div > " +
  "div.header-right.header-user-functions > div:nth-child(5) > a > span"));
if (points != null)
{
    bunifuCustomLabel7.Text = points.Text;
}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for a timer:

```
var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer((x) =>
{
    MethodToUpdateForm();   
}, null, 0, (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new to c# but what would go into MethodtoUpdateform?

Comment: That method was just my generic naming for the method or actions you wish to perform every 5 or (x) minutes. Hopefully that is clear, otherwise let me know and I can further elaborate.

Comment: So basically the code that I have would go in the timer variable

Comment: Yes that is correct. Whatever action you want (which I believe you want to update a label) would go in here.

Comment: It says I can't convert from 'double' to 'int' on the Timespan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds

Comment: Sorry about that, please see my edit for the fix. The TimeSpan just needs to be cast to an int. (int)

Comment: Ok that works but now I am getting an error with "Cross-thread operation not valid" Sorry for all the trouble sir

Comment: Oh, I see. You probably need to user the Windows Forms timer instead. So it would be System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Threading.Timer. I edited my answer again to reflect what I'm saying.

Comment: I got it to work thanks for the help !

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you.